# iptables - logging new connections

Tags: iptables, firewall

The configuration: Internet -- [eth0 -- wlan0] -- devices.

I am trying to detect 'new connection' packets from the Internet destined for a device on the wireless network.

I have tried the following (and a few other combinations), with no success.

```
% iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state NEW -j LOG
```

Any pointers appreciated.

As asked, this is output of iptables-save:

```
% iptables-save
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [448:96744]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [642:55726]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [195:18496]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [155570:16184887]
:INPUT ACCEPT [124785:11715304]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1126:93169]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13705:987253]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar  1 13:55:42 2021
```

Comment: Are there other rules in the firewall? Please show us a *complete* firewall, better in the form of `iptables-save` output. Also, why are you sure there should be such connections? If there is a NAT of some kind, it is possible no new connections from Internet to LAN could be made unless there are forwarded ports.

Comment: The firewall is essentially empty. (It's an off-the-shelf router I am experimenting with). I have added the output of iptables-save above

Comment: My very tentative explanation is that the router's kernel is unlikely to track connection state for traffic that flows through it. Connection state is probably tracked on the destination device only. Just to check if logging works in principle, I would start without the `--state NEW` (even if it overflows your message log), then think of another way to detect and log new connections.

Comment: @berndbausch No, you're wrong. Connection tracking is well described and also you can just see the source code and convince yourself it stores and uses almost all information from the packet header. It would be impossible to NAT some protocols like GRE and there were no "NAT helpers" if there were only "destination" tracking. NAT helpers themselves already are things that consider not only headers, but even contents of a some packets.

Comment: I stand corrected, and thanks for that information. Stuff to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule consider packets that enter the router via `eth0`, are routed to be output from `wlan0` and are *new* from the point of the connection tracker.

What is *new*? It is basically not what is *expected* or *assured* or *replied* and so on. When packet travels connection tracker, it is searched in its state table. The table contains source and destination addresses and ports, a *state*, timestamps when packets travelled either way, amount of data transmitted over this connection. If packet header data corresponds to some record in the table, that record is updated (for example, "expected" may be turned to "assured"), and a packet is assigned a connection tag. This packet won't travel any chain in the *nat* table; instead, if some transformations were recorded in the connection tracker table record, those are applied. And, of course, this packet will **not** be considered as starting *new* connection.

But, if nothing relevant is found in the table, a new record is created, packet is travelled through chains in the *nat* table and it is assigned a *new* connection tag.

By the way, `-m state` is an obsolete syntax. A modern is `-m conntrack` and its `--ctstate` parameter. (Now both seem to be handled by the same module, but historically these were different modules in the Netfilter.)

---

Now, think how packets are going through your router. A [Netfilter packet flow diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) is very helpful here. So, let's assume someone behind `wlan0` initiates a connection to internet. Then some packet appears from `wlan0`, it first recorded into the connection tracker, then router hopefully routes it to be output via `eth0`. Then it traverses a `filter FORWARD` chain, there it is checked against your "logging" rule (it doesn't apply, obviously). Then it traverses `nat POSTROUTING`, where it encounter a `MASQUERADE` rule. It is SNAT'ed by the rule, and a connection tracker record is updated with translation information, so follow-ups will be translated the same, and replies will be detected and translated back. Then it is output from `eth0`.

Any reply or follow-up packets will be assigned to this connection tracker record, and will **not** be tagged as *new*. They will be tagged as *established*, so they will **not** trigger your "logging" rule.

Also, if the connection is known to be, say, FTP control (tcp to port 21) and *ftp connection tracker helper* is enabled, it will scan all following packets of this connection for FTP data connection parameters (this is simplified explanation, but correct). If it sees them, the helper creates another connection tracker entry, with the data it captured from FTP control packet. The connection is created in *related* state; therefore, when FTP server connects back to the client to establish the data connection, first packet of that connection will **not** be tagged *new*, but *related* So it will **not** trigger your "logging" rule too.

---

Are there possible any packets that come in via `eth0`, must be output from `wlan0` and will not be answers to the connections initiated from inside? Yes. Some system behind `eth0` must have a route to the network which is behind `wlan0` via the address assigned to the `eth0` of your router. Then, if that system tries to use that route and send a packet to the address from wlan0 network (other than your router's address), such packet **will** trigger your "logging" rule.

Are there such systems in your setup? I don't know, but usually there aren't: you wouldn't install a NAT rule in the case there is route facing back your wlan0 network, the NAT wouldn't needed in that case to have replies back. So I think it's unlikely, however, possible.

Another possibility is DNAT case. Suppose you want to forward some port of your router to some machine inside, for example, forward tcp port 80 to the web server somewhere behind wlan0. Then you'll install a rule like this: `iptables -A PREROUTING -d <eth0-address> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <webserver-behind-wlan0-address>`. The tcp packet destined to the eth0 address port 80 will be recorded into NAT table and tagged *new*, destination address changed to some address behind wlan0 and then routing will decide it must be sent out via wlan0. So it'll traverse `filter FORWARD`, where it **will** trigger your "logging" rule. Follow-up packets will be *established*, so they won't trigger that rule.

But you have no DNAT rules. So this scenario could not work.

---

A conclusion: I presume you have no systems behind eth0 which have routes to the network behind wlan0 via your router, and also you have no DNAT rules. There will be no packets in your network which could trigger this "logging" rule.

I already made this conclusion in my first comment to your question, here is just a verbose explanation how I concluded that.